# C# extension methods analogue in C++

Tags: c++, extension-methods

C# has this little nice feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

This is really cool. Let me give you an example:

I want to add `concat` method to `std::vector` but I don't want to inherit it. This feature would be very useful. Do you have any analogues feature in C++ that allows to add a function to a type without inheriting from the original type? I am asking for a language-level feature, please.

Comment: ...and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922112/c-extension-functions

Comment: To be clear, C# extension methods do not _add_ a function _to a type_. It is exactly what it is declared to be: a static method in a static class. The type is not being extended; The "set of operators" that act on the type is what's being extended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ this is not directly possible; that being said, you could implement a function that has a reference to a `std::vector` as a first argument, serving a similar purpose as an extension method (which more or less are just syntactic sugar for that).

Comment: Calling a function with an argument is exactly what extensions not..

The essence of the extension method is to synthetically extend the class rather then call a general function that (possibly) does a side effect on its argument.

Comment: @QT-1 What do you mean? Isn't calling a function with an argument literally what an extension method is? The [first argument to an extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) is always "this Foo foo". I'm pretty sure that the magic that lets me say foo.extensionBar() is just syntactic sugar...

Comment: Yes, @QT-1 is totally right in the sense that the first argument of the extension method is hidden from the caller, who uses the same syntax as for a method. On the other hand, it is correct that technically an extension method is syntactic sugar for the approach above - the reference to the instance has to somewhere in the end.

Answer (score 1):

A free function might be your friend here e.g.

```
namespace VectorMethods
{
    std::string contat(const std::vector<std::string>& vec)
    {
        // return result of concatenating vector
    }
}
```